# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' when call XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know why the "li" second (with class="desc") is always empty. Why i can't set innerHTML for it, while i can set innerHTML for the first li tag. If i use :

```
e.parentElement.children[0].innerHTML = "abc";
```

<== Then it works fine. How to fix this error ?. Here is my full code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Get Content</button>
<div id="demo"></div>
<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var oglasiHTML = '<div id="select">' +
                '<ul>' +
                    '<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return readmore(\'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=imdb+language:PHP\',this);">readmore</a></li>' +
                    '<li class="desc"></li>' +
                '</ul>' +
            '</div>';
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = oglasiHTML;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=imdb+language:PHP", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
function readmore(url,e) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        e.parentElement.children[1].innerHTML = "abc";
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working because `e.parentElement` returns the `li` node. Use [Node.nextSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) to get the next `li` node:

```
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    e.parentElement.nextSibling.innerHTML = "abc"; //--> <li class="desc"></li>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
e.parentElement.parentElement.children[1].innerHTML = "abc";
```

e is your current element; i.e `a`
parent of `a` is `li`.

Now `li` have only one child `a`

parent of current `li` is `ul`.

now `ul` have two child.

And you can add value to it